# How to get real String from item.text and convert it to float on Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting a number from `item.text` input. I want to convert that string to float. Now I'm trying with this:

```
deci = @wert.text.to_s
para deci.to_f
```

The problem is, that I get something with `'232.2'` instead of `"232.2"`. The
`.to_f` function is only working with strings with the type of `"..."`

Comment: It should work for both, What is the error/wrong resonse you are getting???

Comment: There's something wrong with your syntax if you're having problems with that. Both `'` and `"` quotes are equivalent for simple text. The only difference is how special characters like `\` and `#{...}` are handled.

Comment: I get 0.0 as result whatever i type as floatnumber. so it is in a wrong format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
@wert.text.first.to_s
```

instead of

```
@wert.text.to_s
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
Float("232.2")
```

Comment: if you do `Float(@wert.text)`, does it return you a float like you expect?

Comment: no i dont get anything, i guess @wert.text is nothing with '' and ""?

Answer (score 0):

In my `irb`(`ruby 1.9.3p429`), it is working fine:

```
"232.2".to_f ==> 232.2            '232.2'.to_f ==> 232.2
```

Other options you have:

```
Float("232.2") ==> 232.2            Float('232.2') ==> 232.2
eval("232.2") ==> 232.2            eval('232.2') ==> 232.2
```

Comment: Can you please **not** suggest using `eval` for this sort of thing?